# How to write if condition inside of the logstash grok pattern?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

My question is related to logstash grok pattern. I created below pattern that's working fine but the big problem is not string values. Sometimes; "Y" and "age" can be null so my grok pattern not create any log in elasticseach. It is not working properly. I need to tell my grok pattern :

```
if(age is null || age i empty){
updatefield["age",0]
}
```

but I don't know how to make it. by the way; I checked many solutions by googling but it is directly related to my problem.

```
input {
  file {
       path => ["C:/log/*.log"]
        start_position => "beginning" 
        discover_interval => 10
        stat_interval => 10
        sincedb_write_interval => 10
        close_older => 10
        codec => multiline { 
        pattern => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}\|"
        negate => true
        what => "previous" 
       }
  }
}

filter {  
 grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:formattedDate}.* X: %{DATA:X} Y: %{NUMBER:Y} Z: %{DATA:Z} age: %{NUMBER:age:int} "}
        }   
 date {
            timezone => "Europe/Istanbul"
            match => ["TimeStamp", "ISO8601"]
             }  
    json{
        source => "request"
        target => "parsedJson"

    }   
    mutate {
    remove_field => [ "path","message","tags","@version"]

    }
}   

output {  

    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
  elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "http://localhost:9200" ]
         index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM}"

    }   
}
```

Comment: It is not possible, but you can do multiline pattern. [Here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/grok-expression-in-if-condition-filter/58615/3) is a post in discuss elasticsearch to do it in a proper way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if your fields exists or are empty using [conditionals](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#conditionals) with your filter,

```
filter {
  if ![age] or [age] == "" { 
       mutate {
         update => { "age" => "0" }
       }    
   } 
}
```